# How to run class with @testFactory annotation from the console with gradle as build tool?

Tags: java, gradle, junit, junit5

I'm trying to run a TestFactory annotated method from console.
I'm getting the error as "Could not find matching test for pattern:"
Is it because of dependency issue?
I've included all the dependencies mentioned in https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build
The same code runs with @test annotation. Please help me run this as testFactory.

I'm running as ./gradlew clean tests --stacktrace -Dtests.single=TestClass on terminal.

Comment: Have you tried `./gradlew --stacktrace clean test --tests TestClass`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried this and am getting
 Execution failed for task ':proj:test'.